# Agregar columna a data frame basado en condición sobre otra columna

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

Tengo un dataframe con nombre de países y su respectivo código. Necesito ordenar el data frame para que finalmente obtener un panel data.
Tengo el siguiente data frame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A través de la librería *tidyr* he creado una variable pais (columna) con su valor correspondiente
de la siguiente forma:

```
library(readxl)
d1 <- read_excel("C:/excel.xlsx")
View(d1)

d1 <- data.frame(d1)

library(tidyr)

d2 <- d1 %>% gather(pais, valor, 2:ncol(d1))
```

obtuve los siguientes resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busco tener

```
year id_pais nombre_pais Valor
1960 ARG     Argentina   
1961 ARG     Argentina
.
.
1965 ARG     Argentina    12.9
.
.
1970 BOL     Bolivia      19.5
```

Comment: Tienes dos headers, lo mejor es cargar las dos primeras líneas para crear un diccioanrio de códigos, luego cargar desde la fila 2 en adelante, aplicar `gather` y luego pegar el diccionario.